added data frames with unequal number of rows
I have two data sets.
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c(13,15,17,12,19,12,18,16,15,17,9,12,8,16,15,10,13,11,6,11,16,5,18,15,12,8,18,5,17,16),
  v2 = c(14,12,16,16,6,10,9,6,14,11,16,6,12,17,6,11,12,7,12,9,11,18,5,6,13,10,8,8,17,15)
)

df2  <- data.frame(
  c15 = c(15,12,8,18,5,17,16),
  c22 = c(11,18,5,6,13,8,15)
)

I want to combine both data frames so that df2 is added as columns aligned to the last row. The effect I want
> df
   v1 v2 c15 c22
1  13 14  NA  NA
2  15 12  NA  NA
3  17 16  NA  NA
4  12 16  NA  NA
5  19  6  NA  NA
6  12 10  NA  NA
7  18  9  NA  NA
8  16  6  NA  NA
9  15 14  NA  NA
10 17 11  NA  NA
11  9 16  NA  NA
12 12  6  NA  NA
13  8 12  NA  NA
14 16 17  NA  NA
15 15  6  NA  NA
16 10 11  NA  NA
17 13 12  NA  NA
18 11  7  NA  NA
19  6 12  NA  NA
20 11  9  NA  NA
21 16 11  NA  NA
22  5 18  NA  NA
23 18  5  NA  NA
24 15  6  15  11
25 12 13  12  18
26  8 10   8   5
27 18  8  18   6
28  5  8   5  13
29 17 17  17   8
30 16 15  16  15

Using merge is not possible because there is no common column.
